# Abstract Class - Why is my protected method publicly accessible?

Tags: java

Why can I access the `doStuff()` Method in the main method below? Since `doStuff()` is protected, I would expect that only `TestClassImplementation` has access to it.

```
public abstract class AbstractTestClass {
    protected void doStuff()
    {
        System.out.println("doing stuff ...");
    }
}

public class TestClassImplementation extends AbstractTestClass{

}

public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClassImplementation test = new TestClassImplementation();
        test.doStuff(); //why can I access the doStuff() Method here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all these classes in the same package?

Comment: yes they are all in the same package

Comment: Well that explains it.

Comment: Ok, thx, I guess protected works differently in java than it does in php ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like `MyProgram` class is in the same package of your `AbstractTestClass`. If so, then it can access to `protected` and `public` members of the classes in the same package.

Covered in Java tutorials:

```
Modifier    Class Package Subclass   World
public      Y     Y       Y          Y
protected   Y     Y       Y          N
no modifier Y     Y       N          N
private     Y     N       N          N
```

In order to *fix* this, just move the `AbstractTestClass` to another package. Similar for other relevant classes.

More info:

- [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 3):

In Java the keyword `protected` includes access not only from subclasses, but actually the entire package. There is no way to prevent that.